# Как поменять порядок полей в json, используя GSON library?

Tags: android, json, gson

Допустим есть класс модель

```
class Movie {
    String id;
    String title;
    int year;
    Production production;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }

    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public Production getProduction() {
        return production;
    }
};
```

Используя [gson](https://github.com/google/gson), получается такая json-строка

```
movies: [
  {
    id: "771305050",
    title: "Straight Outta Compton",
    production: {
      director: "F. Gary Gray"
      screenplay: "Jonathan Herman"
    },
    year: 2015,
  },
  { 
    id: "771357161",
    title: "Mission: Impossible Rogue Nation",
    production: {
      director: "Christopher McQuarrie",
      screenplay: "Christopher McQuarrie"
    },
    year: 2015
  }
]
```

Как видно, порядок полей в классе-модели был другой: `production` в json-строке теперь раньше, чем `year`. Возможно ли как-то, не отказываясь от библиотеки, сделать порядок как в классе модели?

Comment: В json порядок полей в объекте не определён. Может быть, можно сделать определённый порядок, но это задача очень странная. Вы ведь обращаетесь к полям по ключам, вам не нужен порядок там.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно [спецификации JSON](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7159.txt), объект представляет собой:

> An object is an unordered collection of zero or more name/value
>      pairs, where a name is a string and a value is a string, number,
>      boolean, null, object, or array.

Соответственно приложение не должно опираться на предположения о порядке следования полей.

Теперь ближе к делу:

Gson не имеет средств могущих контролировать порядок следования полей (по крайней мере, я не слышал о таких). Но например, Jackson есть такие средства, в частности аннотация `@JsonPropertyOrder`

То есть если прямо очень надо либо надо писать собственный десериалайзер (Gson это позволяет делать) или использовать Jackson